# How do I resolve this error? TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replaceAll')

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I understand the line is reading undefined on `userName` and that that means useName doesn't exist on `user`. I tried looking for places where ther `user` is being defined/instantiated but it's still tough for me to narrow it down exactly to the file and the solution. Any help or advice on how to narrow down to find the problem or how to fix this is greatly appreciated, thanks!

exact error line of code --> `{user.userName.replaceAll(' ', '')}`

File with the error is SuggestedAccounts.tsx -->

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import Image from 'next/image';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { GoVerified } from 'react-icons/go';

import useAuthStore from '../store/authStore';
import { IUser } from '../types';

const SuggestedAccounts = () => {
  const { fetchAllUsers, allUsers } = useAuthStore();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchAllUsers();
  }, [fetchAllUsers]);
  return (
    <div className="xl:border-b-2 border-gray-200 pb-4">
      <p className="text-gray-500 font-semibold m-3 mt-4 hidden: xl:block">
        Suggested Accounts
      </p>
      <div>
        {allUsers.slice(0, 6).map((user: IUser) => (
          <Link href={`/profile/${user._id}`} key={user._id}>
            <div className="flex gap-3 hover:bg-primary p-2 cursor-pointer font-semibold rounded">
              <div className="w-8 h-8">
                <Image
                  src={user.image}
                  width={34}
                  height={34}
                  className="rounded-full"
                  alt="user profile"
                  layout="responsive"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="hidden xl:block">
                <p className="flex gap-1 items-center text-md font-bold text-primary lowercase">
                  {user.userName.replaceAll(' ', '')}
                  <GoVerified className="text-blue-400" />
                </p>
                <p className="capitalize text-gray-400 text-xs">
                  {user.userName}
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Link>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SuggestedAccounts;
```

authStore.tsx -->

```
import create from 'zustand';
import { persist } from 'zustand/middleware';
import axios from 'axios';
import { BASE_URL } from '../utils';

const authStore = (set: any) => ({
  userProfile: null,
  allUsers: [],

  addUser: (user: any) => set({ userProfile: user }),
  removeUser: () => set({ userProfile: null }),

  fetchAllUsers: async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/api/users`);

    set({ allUsers: response.data });
  },
});

const useAuthStore = create(
  persist(authStore, {
    name: 'auth',
  })
);

export default useAuthStore;
```

pages/profile/[id].tsx -->

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Image from 'next/image';
import { GoVerified } from 'react-icons/go';
import axios from 'axios';

import VideoCard from '../../components/VideoCard';
import NoResults from '../../components/NoResults';
import { IUser, Video } from '../../types';
import { BASE_URL } from '../../utils';

interface IProps {
  data: {
    user: IUser;
    userVideos: Video[];
    userLikedVideos: Video[];
  };
}

const Profile = ({ data }: IProps) => {
  const [showUserVideos, setShowUserVideos] = useState(true);
  const [videosList, setVideosList] = useState<Video[]>([]);
  const { user, userVideos, userLikedVideos } = data;
  const videos = showUserVideos ? 'border-b-2 border-black' : 'text-gray-400';
  const liked = !showUserVideos ? 'border-b-2 border-black' : 'text-gray-400';

  useEffect(() => {
    if (showUserVideos) {
      setVideosList(userVideos);
    } else {
      setVideosList(userLikedVideos);
    }
  }, [showUserVideos, userLikedVideos, userVideos]);

  return (
    <div className="w-full">
      <div className="flex gap-6 md:gap-10 mb-4 bg-white w-full">
        <div className="w-16 h-16 md:w-32 m:h-32">
          <Image
            src={user.image}
            width={120}
            height={120}
            className="rounded-full"
            alt="user profile"
            layout="responsive"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-col justify-center">
          <p className="md:text-2xl tracking-wider flex gap-1 items-center justify-center text-md font-bold text-primary lowercase">
            {user.userName.replaceAll(' ', '')}
            <GoVerified className="text-blue-400" />
          </p>
          <p className="capitalize md:text-xl text-gray-400 text-xs">
            {user.userName}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <div className="flex gap-10 mb-10 mt-10 border-b-2 border-gray-200 bg-white w-full">
          <p
            className={`text-xl font-semibold cursor-pointer mt-2 ${videos}`}
            onClick={() => setShowUserVideos(true)}
          >
            Videos
          </p>
          <p
            className={`text-xl font-semibold cursor-pointer mt-2 ${liked}`}
            onClick={() => setShowUserVideos(false)}
          >
            Liked
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className="flex gap-6 flex-wrap md:justify-start">
          {videosList.length > 0 ? (
            videosList.map((post: Video, idx: number) => (
              <VideoCard post={post} key={idx} />
            ))
          ) : (
            <NoResults
              text={`No ${showUserVideos ? '' : 'Liked'} Videos Yet`}
            />
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export const getServerSideProps = async ({
  params: { id },
}: {
  params: { id: string };
}) => {
  const res = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/api/profile/${id}`);

  return {
    props: { data: res.data },
  };
};

export default Profile;
```

utils/index.ts -->

```
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';

export const BASE_URL = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL;

export const createOrGetUser = async (response: any, addUser: any) => {
  type Decoded = { name: string; picture: string; sub: string };

  const { name, picture, sub }: Decoded = jwt_decode(response.credential);
  //   const decoded = ({
  //     name: string,
  //     picture: string,
  //     sub: string,
  //   } = jwt_decode(response.credential));

  //   const { name, picture, sub } = decoded;

  const user = {
    _id: sub,
    _type: 'user',
    userName: name,
    image: picture,
  };

  addUser(user);

  await axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/api/auth`, user);
};
```

utils/queries.ts -->

```
  const query = `*[_type == "post"] | order(_createdAt desc){
    _id,
     caption,
       video{
        asset->{
          _id,
          url
        }
      },
      userId,
      postedBy->{
        _id,
        userName,
        image
      },
    likes,
    comments[]{
      comment,
      _key,
      postedBy->{
      _id,
      userName,
      image
    },
    }
  } `;

  return query;
};

export const postDetailQuery = (postId: string | string[]) => {
  const query = `*[_type == "post" && _id == '${postId}']{
    _id,
     caption,
       video{
        asset->{
          _id,
          url
        }
      },
      userId,
    postedBy->{
      _id,
      userName,
      image
    },
     likes,
    comments[]{
      comment,
      _key,
      postedBy->{
        _ref,
      _id,
    },
    }
  }`;
  return query;
};

export const searchPostsQuery = (searchTerm: string | string[]) => {
  const query = `*[_type == "post" && caption match '${searchTerm}*' || topic match '${searchTerm}*'] {
    _id,
     caption,
       video{
        asset->{
          _id,
          url
        }
      },
      userId,
    postedBy->{
      _id,
      userName,
      image
    },
likes,
    comments[]{
      comment,
      _key,
      postedBy->{
      _id,
      userName,
      image
    },
    }
  }`;
  return query;
};

export const singleUserQuery = (userId: string | string[]) => {
  const query = `*[_type == "user" && _id == '${userId}']`;

  return query;
};

export const allUsersQuery = () => {
  const query = `*[_type == "user"]`;

  return query;
};

export const userCreatedPostsQuery = (userId: string | string[]) => {
  const query = `*[ _type == 'post' && userId == '${userId}'] | order(_createdAt desc){
    _id,
     caption,
       video{
        asset->{
          _id,
          url
        }
      },
      userId,
    postedBy->{
      _id,
      userName,
      image
    },
 likes,

    comments[]{
      comment,
      _key,
      postedBy->{
      _id,
      userName,
      image
    },
    }
  }`;

  return query;
};

export const userLikedPostsQuery = (userId: string | string[]) => {
  const query = `*[_type == 'post' && '${userId}' in likes[]._ref ] | order(_createdAt desc) {
    _id,
     caption,
       video{
        asset->{
          _id,
          url
        }
      },
      userId,
    postedBy->{
      _id,
      userName,
      image
    },
 likes,

    comments[]{
      comment,
      _key,
      postedBy->{
      _id,
      userName,
      image
    },
    }
  }`;

  return query;
};

export const topicPostsQuery = (topic: string | string[]) => {
  const query = `*[_type == "post" && topic match '${topic}*'] {
    _id,
     caption,
       video{
        asset->{
          _id,
          url
        }
      },
      userId,
    postedBy->{
      _id,
      userName,
      image
    },
 likes,

    comments[]{
      comment,
      _key,
      postedBy->{
      _id,
      userName,
      image
    },
    }
  }`;

  return query;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access user from mapping allUsers before you've fetched anything in the useEffect.

Try to conditionally render after you've got data back from the fetch

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).